# Specific examples of an increasing and decreasing function

Tags: calculus

My textbook shows 4 graphs of curves: Increasing and concave down, Increasing and concave up, Decreasing and concave down, and Decreasing and concave up.
Please provide me with specific real life examples of each graph to help me visualize what each graph could represent.

Comment: Anything modeled by a parabola or modeled by the square root function (or its negative). The exercises in your text should have many such examples.

Comment: These things tell you information about what a graph looks like. If you are modeling some real world application you may have a function and looking at where some function is increasing/decreasing and whether it is concave up/concave down can give insight to what may be going on in this model. These things can be very useful in optimization  and I’m sure many other applications

Comment: My book does show many examples of concave up and down graphs but gives no real life situations which is what my question is asking for...

Answer (score 0):

@bigollo

- Let $f(t)$ is increasing and concave down on a time-interval, $t \in I$. This means the value of $f$ will keep increasing but with a *decreasing-rate* (because concave down). For example : $f(t)$ could be a **position** at time $t$ of a *sprinter* breaking, trying to stop (still forward but not accelerating anymore).
- Conversely, if $f(t)$ is increasing but concave up, then this means $f$ is increasing in value and also with an *increasing-rate*. The increase gets higher in time. An example : $f(t)$ could be a **position** at time $t$ of a *sprinter* *accelerating* (from the start-until some point in the race).

You may improvise or extend from these examples.

Also, the application is not always about *dynamics*. It may be used to model a certain shape :

- A **circle** on the 1st quadrant is a *decreasing and concave down*.
  Hope this helps.
- A **playful slide** might be modeled by a *decreasing* function with a combination of  *concave up* and *concave down*

Hope this helps.